# Función al hacer scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function Ventanica(url,titulo,ancho,alto) { //configuro la ventanica
 $("<div id='"+titulo+"' class='loaderchachi'><div id='loader'>&nbsp;</div></div>").dialog({ "title" : titulo , "width" : ancho , "height" : alto ,
  close : function(){ $(this).dialog("destroy"); $('.Li'+titulo).attr("onclick", "Ventanica('"+url+"','"+titulo+"','"+ancho+"','"+alto+"');"); $("#dock"+titulo).removeClass("active").addClass("cerrado"); } })
 .dialogExtend({
 "autoOpen": false, "closable" : true, "maximizable" : true, "minimizable" : true, "collapsable" : false, "dblclick" : "maximize", "titlebar" : "transparent", "minimizeLocation" : "right",
 "icons" : {
  "close" : "ui-icon-close",
  "maximize" : "ui-icon-plus",
  "minimize" : "ui-icon-minus",
  "restore" : "ui-icon-bullet"
 },
 "load" : function(){
  $("#loader").html('<div class="loader-container"><div class="spinchachi"></div></div>');
  $("#"+titulo).load('https://'+url, function(response, status, xhr) { $("#loader").html('');
  if ( status == "error" ) { var msg = "Ocurrio un error al cargar contenido remoto: "; $().toastmessage('showToast', { text : msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText , sticky : false, type : 'alert' }); }
  $('.Li'+titulo).attr("onclick", '$("#'+titulo+'").dialog("moveToTop");');
  $("#dock"+titulo).addClass("active");
 });
 },
 "beforeMaximize" : function(evt) { EfectosmenuA(); $('#micromenusuario').css('top', 40); $('.Li'+titulo).attr("onclick", '$("#'+titulo+'").dialogExtend("restore");'); $("#dock"+titulo).removeClass("abierto").addClass("active"); },
 "beforeRestore" : function(evt){ EfectosmenuC(); $('#micromenusuario').css('top', 10); $("#dock"+titulo).removeClass("abierto").addClass("active"); },
 "beforeMinimize" : function(evt) { $("#dock"+titulo).removeClass("active").addClass("abierto"); },
 });

};

  
 $("#Ean").scroll(function(){

  if ($(document).height() - $("#Ean").height() == $("#Ean").scrollTop()) {
alert("Hemos llegado abajo");
   }
 
 
/*
 //alert($(document).height());
 if ($("#Ean").scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $("#Ean").height()){
  pagina++;
  cargardatos();
  alert("Hemos llegado abajo");
 }
*/
});
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<button onclick="Ventanica('es.lipsum.com','Ean','500','300')">Pulsame</button>
```

estoy intentando hacer un scroll infinito con jquery pero no consigo entender el funcionamiento.

este es el código que tengo de momento:

```
$('.resultados_ConsEan').scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
        alert("Hemos llegado abajo");
    }
});
```

el scroll en vez de en toda la ventana intento que se haga solo al llegar abajo de un div con la clase resultados_ConsEan en esta capa muestro resultados de un loop de php con lo que el tamaño es dinámico.

Entiendo que en vez de window tendría que poner la capa en cuestión, pero lo pongo y pasa de mi. no entiendo muy bien la resta de document.height menos window height con lo que no tengo muy claro que selectores tengo que poner ahi...

El div esta dentro de una ventana dialog de jquery ui con lo que document no se si se refiere a ese dialog o a la pagina completa.

Actualización:

He conseguido que se dispare la función poniendo en .scroll el id del dialog en este caso es #Ean

con lo que he cambiado la función a esto:

```
$("#Ean").scroll(function(){
    alert($("#Ean").height());
    if ($("#Ean").scrollTop() == $('.resultados_ConsEan').height() - $("#Ean").height()){
        alert("Hemos llegado abajo");
    }
});
```

pero sigue sin funcionar. he puesto la alerta para saber los tamaños de `#Ean` y `.resultatados_ConsEan` y estos son los valores que me da:

```
#Ean = 554.3625001907349
.resultatados_ConsEan 2820
```

No he conseguido que en el ejemplo cargue una pagina dentro del dialog, pero la idea es que dentro hay un texto y al llegar al final del scroll de dentro del dialog salte una función ( en este caso de prueba una alerta )

Comment: ¿Puedes crear un [mcve] para que podamos verlo en funcionamiento y ver el problema?

Comment: voy a intentarlo, pero es un código complejo de replicar :_(

Comment: Solo con el html y JS, para ver el alert saltar o no saltar cuando corresponda. Porque el error realmente es JS, ¿no?

Comment: creo que el error lo tengo en el calculo del tamaño del fin del scroll... estoy intentando replicarlo a ver si soy capaz.